# Pre Commit Hook for SVN not behaving as expected with Enterprise Architect

Tags: svn, enterprise-architect

I am using a pre-commit hook, on my SVN (Visual SVN server and Tortoise Client). It was working perfectly. Now we want to commit via enterprise architect(where we give the svn.exe address). Now the pre-commit hook blocks the commit. 
Below is the commit hook

```
REM Pre Commit hook for having a comment of at least 20 characters. 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2
set SVNLOOK="%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnlook.exe"

SET M=
REM Concatenate all the lines in the commit message
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %%g IN (`%SVNLOOK% log -t %TXN% %REPOS%`) DO SET M=!M!%%g

REM Make sure M is defined
SET M=0%M%

REM Here the 20 is the length we require
IF NOT "%M:~20,1%"=="" goto NORMAL_EXIT

:ERROR_TOO_SHORT
echo "Commit note must be at least 20 letters" >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_EXIT
exit /b 1

REM All checks passed, so allow the commit.
:NORMAL_EXIT
exit 0
```

Please suggest your solution for this.
The Error code I get is `E165001`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789148/svn-e165001-commit-blocked-by-pre-commit-hook-exit-code-255-with-no-output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837754/svn-commit-blocked-by-pre-commit-hook-exit-code-3-with-output

Comment: @ThomasKilian I can not find a solution in any of the links provided by you

Comment: It seems that the string passed from EA changes somehow!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise Architect, while committing folder adds it's own comments. "Adding Folders". It only commits the addition at one time and content the next time. That is the reason the above hook failed as it was not 20 characters.